# How to get the books liked by facebook user from the array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have used the Facebook PHP SDK to fetch the books user liked.

```
$books = $facebook->api('/me/books');
```

After decoding the JSON I get the output array something like this:

```
Array ( 
[data] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [category] => Book [name] => Steve Jobs by Walter Isaacson [id] => 152707268157952 [created_time] => 2012-12-05T15:10:14+0000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [category] => Book [name] => Restful Web Services [id] => 106832016007551 [created_time] => 2012-12-10T10:26:45+0000 ) 
[2] => Array ( [category] => Book [name] => DOS for Dummies [id] => 112172905468817 [created_time] => 2012-12-05T15:10:14+0000 )
....
....
....
)
```

Now what I want to do is to separate the [name] and create a new array for the book name. What should be the loop for doing this?

**EDIT:**
First I am checking if the array is not empty, not sure what to do next. I am trying something like this:

```
foreach($books['data'] as $booksliked){
    if(!empty($booksliked['data'])) {
        foreach($booksliked['data']['name'] as $blikesData){
        //Not sure what to put here 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look and correct me.

Comment: you can create another array having name like wing lian does in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work

```
<?php
$books_from_fb = $facebook->api('/me/books');
$books = array();
foreach ($books_from_fb['data'] as $book_arr) {
    $books[] = $book_arr['name'];
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: $books_from_fb = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE); I tried that.

Comment: if (is_array($books_from_fb))
{                                                                                }                                                                                  I checked this and it worked fine. I think that the problem with me is $books_from_fb is not an array data.